# Create big table in MySql with many foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an App where I have to save Information About User Educations
then I am going to show it to them. 
Each user may have 1, 2 or more Educations.
I am creating this table with laravel Schema builder. Here is code

```
    Schema::create('educations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->date('from')->nullable();
        $table->date('to')->nullable();
        $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('university_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('faculty_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('speciality_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('degree_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('image', 100)->nullable();
        $table->text('additional')->nullable();


        $table->index('university_id');
        $table->index('faculty_id');
        $table->index('country_id');
        $table->index('city_id');
        $table->index('degree_id');
        $table->index('speciality_id');


        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('faculty_id')
            ->references('id')->on('faculties')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('degree_id')
            ->references('id')->on('degrees')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('speciality_id')
            ->references('id')->on('specialities')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('university_id')
            ->references('id')->on('universities')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('country_id')
            ->references('id')->on('countries')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('city_id')
            ->references('id')->on('cities')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

MySql Code:

```
CREATE TABLE `educations` 
( 
    `id`            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
    `user_id`       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `from`          DATE NULL, 
    `to`            DATE NULL, 
    `country_id`    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `city_id`       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `university_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `faculty_id`    INT UNSIGNED NULL, 
    `speciality_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL, 
    `degree_id`     INT UNSIGNED NULL, 
    `image`         VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
    `additional`    TEXT NULL 
) 

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

So i have a question:
when I want to get all Education of One user I hae to run join on almost 7 table or use laravel query builder and run many query when page loads.
Is my database design Correct?

the reason why I am using foreign keys on each column is users must choose their faculties, universities, specialities and etc from my list in database which is variable.

any answer will help. thanks..

Comment: I did it by mistake, sorry, I was looking for SQL

Comment: Have you tried both options? I don't think either option will overload your server, afterall you're only getting the details for one user. The main load on the server will happen when many users user the system at the same time, but my guess is that the change of that is not so big.

Comment: no I tryed nothing, i am creating databases right now.
of course many users must use this app at same time. you think there is not problem?

Comment: _Small Point_ you have 2 `user_id` columns???

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I can see your idea behind these relational structures but
>   in my humble opinion, they are not quite correct because I feel like
>   in some cases the column entries are not directly related with each
>   other. I will give you some examples:
>
> 1. Your table name is 'educations'. 1 user has got several educations
>      but 1 education is not only reserved for 1 user. So this is an
>      n:m-relation, which is why you need 1 table called
>      'educations', 1 for 'users' and 1 table in between those called
>      'user_has_got_education', for example. Your foreign keys land in the
>      latter table with user_id and education_id.
> 2. country_id, city_id, university_id, faculty_id have got no direct relation to educations. Create a table called 'countries'(country_id,
>      country_name, country_population, country_code,.....), then create a
>      table called 'cities' in the same way. Here it gets a bit more
>      difficult because one city_id is not necessarily distinct as there
>      could be TWO city_ids with the city_name='London', one referring to
>      London(UK), one to London(USA, Ohio) and one to London(USA, Kentucky).
>      So what you need here is **at least** a table relation to 'countries'
>      AND a state/county/shire - and even that might not be enough (if there
>      were 2 cities called 'London' in the USA in Ohio state, for example).
>      I call this 'direct relations'. In short, your columns (foreign keys) are in the wrong place, they belong into a 'directly connected brother table', not > into a 'nephew table'.
>
> Try to get from one logical direct
>   relation to another and 'connect' your tables accordingly.
>   I hope I could help a bit, can't really give you a full table structure here, though.

Comment: thanka for answer. I think I have made user-education relationship correctly, because no education is relqted to two user.

Comment: I have created cities, universities, faculties, countries and etc tables already. my question is how can I avoid this foreign keys?